# How do I rotate a movie on the iPad/iPhone?

Tags: ios, video, photos, camera, imovie

I have a movie in my camera roll that is incorrectly rotated.  I would like to rotate it 90 degrees to fix the problem.

Using [this tip](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3282?viewlocale=en_US) I was able to rotate the movie using iMovie.

However, the problem is that the movie is now cropped incorrectly.  The movie is stuck in a landscape orientation instead of a portrait orientation, so that the bottom part of the movie is now cut off.

[image]

How can I rotate a movie in iOS while preserving its proper aspect ratio and dimensions?

Answer (score 5):

I don't have any experience with this app but it seems like it will do what you are after: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-rotate-free/id626614962?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

**On OS X** After rotating your movie in iMovie, click the crop button **(in adjustments)** in the upper left. You should have a green dragable box inwhich you can resize.

Crop button may be in different place per device.

**On iOS** Tap the clip you want to crop. When a magnifying glass appears tap on it. From there you should be able to pinch with two fingers to adjust the frame of the video. This is per latest iMovie update.

Comment: I see no crop button or adjustments button in the upper left in iMovie on my iPad using iOS 7.  See screenshot.  Where is it?

Comment: Sorry for late response. On iOS, tap the clip you want to crop. When a magnifying glass appears tap on it. From there you should be able to pinch with two fingers to adjust the frame of the video. This is per latest iMovie update.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.  I'm able to do as you suggest, but what I end up with is still a landscape-oriented video with my portrait-mode lion in the middle and two giant black bars on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @FlippinFun's answer, since I don't have a high enough score to comment.

**On iOS, using iMovie:** Import the clip into a new project, THEN tap the clip you want to crop. A magnifying glass will appear on top of it. You can just put two fingers on the clip, and rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise.

This works in iMovie for iOS 2.0 (791), and likely earlier versions of iMovie 2.0 for iOS 7.

You can find a detailed description of this in the "detailed help" within the iMovie app.

Comment: Instead of writing an answer to edit someone else's answer, simply click the edit button below the post that you wish to improve.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I have the [iMovie app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/imovie/id377298193?mt=8) installed**

I had a vertical video I wanted to edit in the iMovie app, but it kept saving it as a horizontal 1920x1080 video, so I needed it rotated back to a vertical 1080x1920 video.

Here's what I did:

1. Go to the video and click "Edit"

   [image: Step 1]
2. Tap the three dots

   [image: Step 2]
3. Choose iMovie

   [image: Step 3]
4. Use two fingers to perform a rotating gesture in a desired direction. Once happy with the result, click Done

   [image: Step 4]

Took me a while to figure this out, so I hope this helps